# How do I import product category based on taxonomy vocabulary?

Tags: commerce, feeds

I have a products catalog based on taxonomy vocabulary, as advised the term reference field is on the product content type.

Products imports are working fine, but when I try to import product displays the mapping for term reference (Category vocabulary)does not appear in the target list.

I'm using Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha8, Commerce Feeds 7.x-1.3, Commerce Kickstart 7.x-1.19 and Drupal Core 7.22

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add your taxonomy vocabulary field to the product display.